# Double tap in Resistive touch screen

Tags: android, android-custom-view

I am new in android. I want  double tap event on screen. and i am using  4.2 jellybean  with Resistive touch screen not capacitive.

Is  this possible to get the double tap? If yes please give me any sample code. 
I want double tap on a  Custom View.

Thanks

Comment: try simplegesturelistener

Comment: can you give me some code example? I am totally new in android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. There is the `onDoubleTabListener()`

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.OnDoubleTapListener.html

Comment: Are you sure? with resistive touch screen not with capacitive

Comment: Depends on your device. In our Company we use resistive touchscreens and there it works. If not, you have to count the touches up to two..

Answer (score 0):

onDoubleTapListener as suggested by the first answer should work.

It detects double tap by timing the length between two ACTION_DOWN events, which of course can be detected on a resistive (non multi-touch) screen. Resistive screens won't be able to detect ACTION_POINTER_1_DOWN, which happens when a second finger touches a capacitive screen.